# Microsoft AD FS 3.0 and SAML 2 errors as Exception: 'Element' is an invalid XmlNodeType

Tags: saml, adfs, adfs3.0

I am using ADFS 3.0 and SAML 2. I got errors like:

1. Exception: 
   'Element' is an invalid XmlNodeType. StackTrace:    at
   System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadEndElement()    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSerial1)izer.ReadAuthnRequest(XmlReader
   reader)
2. Passive pipeline error

The saml request was:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="DH7a49776ef7c040d09b2c661821bd5f76" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://auth-dev.ServiceProvider.com/clientOrg/SAML/Login" Destination="https://federation.example.net/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx" IssueInstant="2017-04-20T14:49:35.6414575Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<saml:Issuer>https://auth.ServiceProvider.com/clientOrg</saml:Issuer>
<samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" />
<samlp:forceAuthn>true</samlp:forceAuthn>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

If the error message is too vague, how to further narrow down and trouble shoot this issue raised from the AD FS side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your request is spec compliant. Use a mature SAML2 library to generate the request instead of crafting it by hand.

What is https://auth.ServiceProvider.com/clientOrg using to generate these requests?

if you remove below string, your request becomes compliant.

```
<samlp:forceAuthn>true</samlp:forceAuthn>
```

See sample at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895365.aspx to see how to use forceauthn. I also fixed destination as ad fs endpoint is /adfs/ls not /adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ForceAuthn="true" ID="DH7a49776ef7c040d09b2c661821bd5f76" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://auth-dev.ServiceProvider.com/clientOrg/SAML/Login" Destination="https://federation.example.net/adfs/ls/" IssueInstant="2017-04-20T14:49:35.6414575Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <saml:Issuer>https://auth.ServiceProvider.com/clientOrg</saml:Issuer>
  <samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" />
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Review spec at http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf for correct authnrequest.

Use validators like https://www.samltool.com/validate_xml.php to check if your request is compliant. Others might have more suggestions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for @maweeras's response giving the right direction and tons of good reference. It turns out that, 'samlp:forceAuthn' is an attribute, not an element. weirdly enough, that invalid element did work with the company's existing client. Anyway I downloaded all the 4 schema onto my location machine to verify the xml: saml-schema-assertion-2.0.xsd, saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd, xenc-schema.xsd, xmldsig-core-schema.xsd and customize their xsd reference to point to the local copies .